# Prove $A^c \cap (A \cup B) = (A \cup B^c)^c $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove  $A^c \cap (A \cup B)  = (A \cup B^c)^c $

Start with the left side and try to make it match with the right side:
$A^c \cap (A \cup B)$
$ (A^c \cap A) \cup (A^c \cap B) $
$A^c \cap B$

And I don't know how to keep going after this. How do I match it up with : 
 $ (A \cup B^c)^c $
 I tried using De Morgan's laws but I can't make the left side the same as the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:
$$A^c \cap B = ((A^c \cap B)^c)^c$$
Do you see how to use De Morgan’s law and finish the argument?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{2,3\}$, $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$
2. $A^c=\{3,4\}$, $A\cup B =\{1,2,3\}\Rightarrow A^c\cap (A\cup B)=\{3\}\ \ (1)$
3. $A=\{1,2\},\ B^c=\{1,4\}, A\cup B^c=\{1,2,4\}\Rightarrow (A\cap B^c)^c=\{3\}\ \ (2)$
4. $(1)=(2) \ \ \square.$